# how to calculate days, then a certain number of hours in the days?

Tags: python, numeric, days

I am trying to calculate how many hours I could work If I work four hours a day from today until August 31.  So I used an old file, and tried to modify it (silly me)   It works, sort of, but I get days, then days worked, but I want hours worked.  Here is the code, as bad as it is  :)  I realize I will need to do something entirely different, but I had a go with some code that I wrote to see how many days until my birthday, tried to modify it etc....you get the picture.  yes, I am a newbie.

```
import datetime as dt
todays_date = dt.date(2020, 4, 20)
end_of_summer = dt.date(2020, 8, 31)
days_between = todays_date - end_of_summer
print(days_between)
hours_worked = days_between * -4 
print(hours_worked)
```

output is:
    -133 days, 0:00:00
    532 days, 0:00:00

Comment: That works great, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `timedelta.days`:

```
import datetime as dt
start_date = dt.date(2020, 4, 20)
end_date = dt.date(2020, 8, 31)
date_td = end_date - start_date  # you'll get a datetime.timedelta() instance here

days_between = date_td.days
print(days_between, 'days worked')

hours_worked = days_between * 4 
print(hours_worked, 'hours worked')
```

Output:

```
133 days worked
532 hours worked
```

Also, best practice to calculate timedeltas using start and end dates, so it's easy to remember how to subtract them without getting negative values.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Comment: @Andrew Great to hear. If it helped answer your question, feel free to mark your question as resolved. To learn more, you can check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers